# How to work FIX session on VPN when we connect the apllication with FIX server

Tags: fix-protocol

how the FIX Session works on VPN Tunnel and how many sessions should be created when we send the request on FIX.

my problem is that many session have created  on VPN in one day i.e 30 000 session created so my FIX protocol does not respond properly,

how can I create only one session at a time?

This property file I used for FIX connectivity.

```
FileStorePath=data
ConnectionType=initiator
SenderCompID=XXX
TargetCompID=PSE
#SocketConnectHost=********
StartTime=09:30:00
Asia/Manila
EndTime=16:30:01
Asia/Manila
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=50000
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
Username=*******
Password=*****
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=9
SocketConnectPort=xx
```

```
Session.lookupSession(sessionId).logout("user requested");
```

This function is get used for logging out.But gives the following error:

> FIXIT.1.1:135->PSE, event> (Initiated logout response) FIXIT.1.1:135->PSE, event> (Disconnecting:Received logout response)

This are the logs that are shown on my console.
In the above  the logout is done successfully and the session is removed from my side.But problem is that i didn't understand session is get destroyed or not? And if the session is destroyed then why VPN server is showing the connection is not destroyed? Is the problem from my side or there is a network issue?

Comment: Just a general note: `Asia/Manila` needs to go into the `TimeZone` configuration. I.e. `TimeZone=Asia/Manila`. I assume you are using QuickFIX/J? Moreover, `ReconnectInterval=50000` means that you only try to re-establish the connection after 50000 seconds? That's almost 14 hours?!

Comment: You are only creating one session at a time with the configuration you are having. Or do you mean that you get disconnected 30000 times a day? Can you add some logs to your question? Please attach them for better readability.

Comment: Yes i created only one session and check sessionId if sessionId null than retry the session for create a otherwise heartbeat is running.

Comment: i used thread and socket connectivity and create only one session connection also write a logout function which will be discoonect the session.
but still on VPN many session created and by this issue alert is coming from VPN tunel.

Comment: You do not need to do anything to check if the session is running. QuickFIX/J will heartbeat the other side and drop the connection when there are no heartbeats. Then it will try to reconnect after `ReconnectInterval` seconds. Usually you do not need to manually call `logout`.